# Mounting Electric range when stud is on the center line?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, framing, 240v, range

I am installing 50 amp circuit for a basic  30 " freestanding  electric range,  The range I settled on is 40 amp. The instructions included say they do not recommend a 50 amp power cord from the range to the outlet.

From the install instruction sheet:
"A range cord rated at 40 amps with 125/250 minimum volt range is required. A 50 amp range cord is not recommended..."

"This appliance must be supplied with the proper voltage and frequency, and connected to an individual, properly grounded, 40 amp (minimum) branch circuit protected by a circuit breaker or time-delay fuse."

"NOTE: Use a 4’ power cord to prevent interference with
the storage drawer. Power cords 4.5' to 6’ long may have
to be dressed to allow for proper drawer closing"

---

One one side is  the wall to the exterior of the house. The other side is  cabinet.

It appears there is a stud  16" from the outer wall.   This would mean the outlet center would only be 2" from near center of the stove.
The install instructions state either 3" or 4" off  the center line would be in the zone.
I will be coming up from the basement.

The 4 ft GE cord plug  would stick 1.4375 (1 7/16"  ) from the wall.
Will this plug really be in the way if outlet is in center?, Will the cord really not allow it to go back were it needs?

[Installation instructions here](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/54/54c0d140-5a7d-4ce3-91d3-b1536fc8067a.pdf) (PDF file from Home Depot)

Note the stove is on order. I assume the back looks as in the PDF but can not confirm
I want the outlet to be installed before the oven arrives so I can test the range.

**What is the fix if the only stud is near the center of this oven?**

Comment: Are you confusing #6 wire and 6 foot cord? Your question, as phrased, makes me think you are.

Comment: Is the problem that you think the stud will interfere with proper receptacle placement, or?

Comment: If you want a 50A breaker, you must either use #6 wire, or run conduit and use individual THHN wires of #8 size.  They are allowed to run warmer, allowing 50A, but they require conduit!

Comment: Do you think the outlet needs to be fastened to the stud?

Comment: I am not discussing wire size. It is 6 for a 50 amp outlet   The information quoted is from the manual .  There is no confusion.

Yes I  am concerned that if the outlet has to be mounted on the only stud near by, near the center line of the stove, that the stove will not push  back or something, They make a big deal of where the outlet can be installed in the instructions.  

Platinum Goose. yes I think the outlet should be fastened to the stud.   Everyone I have spoken to says you have to push allot on  wire that size to get teh wires back in . I am open to alternatives.

Comment: Yes, you are correct it probably will interfere if the outlet is in the center and you won't be able to push the stove all the way back to the wall. Adding a section of 2x4 to  the existing stud is one way of spacing it away from center. I put this as a comment because one of the electrical experts will probably come along with a better way of doing it.

Comment: Yes  adding to the framing would be the way  , I was just trying to avoid doing extra work and mess with the tenant still in the apartment coming home each day.  The old world box worked and I even had to flip the outlet 180 due to putting the box too low.   It survived pushing the outlet back in.  I think it will be OK.If it  breaks out than I will have no choice.  OH and that stud, had pipes too close to it and AC on the other.  I would have had to build out the   next stud 3" to get it past the 3" gap needed for the sides of the stove.  I never had these issues with a gas stove.

Answer (score 1):

You're in for some drywall work anyway (and it's going to be behind the range, so it does not have to look too good) so you might as well make a nice big hole and put a horizontal 2x4 between studs (think "firestop" per usual application) and mount your box where it's most convenient for the range install, get the cable into it, then fix the drywall.

You could also add one (or two) chunks of 2x4 to the stud as suggested by Platinum Goose, but it's unlikely to save much, if anything, on drywall repair and is potentially less stable in the face of force applied.

Comment: Couldn't they also use a two-gang old work box and place the receptacle off-center that way?

Comment: That is what I just  spent allot of time tryig to find a spot but due to the ridiculous design of oven backs and placement requirements I gave in to try an old work box.

I used a  thicker box, drilled a side hole  for a cable clamp .  Someone said code does not allow that but the "range box" I bought was thinner plastic and  same 34 cu.in.

Comment: @Mstar -- whoever said that was completely off base, field KO punching/drilling is permitted in boxes (many boxes used in commercial and industrial applications don't come with pre-stamped knockout patterns, expecting the installer to make their own KOs where needed)

Comment: My solution was to use CARLON Super Blue 2-Gang Blue Plastic Old Work 34 cu in. box.. I drilled a hole in the side towards the back for a clamp fitting. I had not installed  the wire in the basement so I had enough to pull out and wire everything before pushing it in the hole and tightening up the ears. However I had installed the box a little too low so without removing the box I was able to flip the outlet over and the drywall was able to handle it but I was careful. the plug has been pulled out and pushed in several times and there doesn't look like they'll be any issue long term.